# How to add class to __sleep?

Tags: php

My example:

```
<?php

class PDO2 {
    private $dsn, $username, $password;

    public function __construct($dsn, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->dsn = $dsn;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }
}

class Connection
{
    protected $link;
    private $dsn, $username, $password;

    public function __construct($dsn, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->dsn = $dsn;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $this->link = new PDO2($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }
}

$c = new Connection('aaaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');

$s = serialize($c);

print_r($s);
```

This return:

> O:10:"Connection":4:{s:7:"*link";O:4:"PDO2":3:{s:9:"PDO2dsn";s:4:"aaaa";s:14:"PDO2username";s:3:"bbb";s:14:"PDO2password";s:3:"ccc";}s:15:"Connectiondsn";s:4:"aaaa";s:20:"Connectionusername";s:3:"bbb";s:20:"Connectionpassword";s:3:"ccc";}

But I would like add to __sleep magic method only PDO2, username and dns:

```
public function __sleep()
{
    return array('dsn', 'username', 'PDO2');
}
```

But I have notice:

```
Notice: serialize(): &quot;PDO2&quot; returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in
```

This:

```
public function __sleep()
{
    return array('dsn', 'username');
}
```

is working well.

How can I pass class PDO2 to __sleep?

Comment: The notice tells you exactly what's going on: there's no member variable (property) in the class `Connection` called `PDO2`. You have assigned an instance of `PDO2` to the property called `link`, so the array that you return in `__sleep()` should be `array( 'dsn', 'username', 'link' )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't clear in your question where `__sleep` was at, but I'm assuming its in `Connection`. Thing is I dont see any `PDO2` property in there.

But you do have this.

```
//$this->link = new PDO2($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);

public function __sleep()
{
    return array('dsn', 'username', 'link');
}
```

Also just from a design standpoint, you don't need to save these in properties

```
private $dsn, $username, $password;
```

Once you made your connection to the DB, they are no longer needed.